# Cannot find org.apache.camel.support.processor.validation.PredicateValidatingProcessor in camel version 3

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to migrate my Apache Camel 2.10.4 apps to 3.0.0M4. After much effort, I'm stuck at this problem which seems to complain about missing dependency

Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/support/processor/validation/PredicateValidatingProcessor.

Looking through the camel version 3.0.0-M4 but I cannot find any jars which have the above class. Googling doesn't turn up anything with regards to the new processor path org.apache.camel.support.processor. I appreciate the help in resolving this issue!

Comment: Make sure you have came-jaxp on the classpath - and also make sure your classpath have all the same version of Camel

Comment: Thanks for the help, resolved the dependency. Turned out the camel 3.0.0-m4 package i downloaded did not contain camel-jaxp jar. Googled and downloaded that and it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have came-jaxp on the classpath - and also make sure your classpath have all the same version of Camel.

I have also added the missing camel-jaxp to the release package of Apache Camel so its included in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

the package path is wrong.
correct path - org.apache.camel.support.processor.PredicateValidationException.